# How to display an image progressively by chunks?

Tags: css, image, transparency, loading

I'm trying to make a loading animation for a website : an image full of candles,  each candle's appearing as the website loads. My mains objectives are :

- Use minimal bandwidth
- Maximize the picture quality
- Create transition between each parts of the picture

So,

1. I tried to use the Photoshop legacy *Export for Web* features but the alpha layer (transparency) that I want to use in PNG is then tessellated, they are also subtle noise on some images.
2. I thought about using a video with embedded transitions but even a VP9 video is bigger than the PNG trick.
3. Using JPEG as well doesn't look great as I can't use transparency and the sum of all pictures are bigger than the PNG trick.

So that's why I wanted to know if someone had any idea how to do such thing ! I would be please to add more information about this if asked !

### Edit

Here's the first picture of the sequence (without any edit to add transparency) : [image: First picture]
And here's the last, there's 19 images total : [image: Last picture]

Comment: Can you get the full image without the candles, and then fade in each candle in separated images? If the background image is the same image without the candles, and each smaller image is correctly positioned, an opacity transition could do the trick without the need for transparency.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to imagine what that would look like exactly. Could you actually show a picture (usually we don't like pictures here, but I think this question warrants one). Anyway, my first idea would be to have one big JPG background image, then a couple of small PNG candle images (on transparent ground) that are initially on `opacity:0.0`; you could then animate their opacity to go up to `1.0` as the page loads. The question is, what are you going to show during the loading of the images? ;)

Comment: @domdom Done. As you'll see the problem is that light bump on rocks, so I can't simply use small png candles on a background

Comment: @mikepa88 The full image is total black as each candle illuminate the cave ! I added pictures of the first and last frame

Comment: @PaulCo then you should have an image for every step. Otherwise the browser should be able to apply lightning effects like a full-fledged 3d engine.

Comment: I count more than 19 candles. Are the images in sequence? I think due to the nature of how a candle flickers the light would not align if you simply swap out the images in sequence. Another thing is the 19 images would end up being either bigger in size than the document itself - even if they are highly optimized progressive jpegs - or so small that the whole idea is ruined because you can't see a thing.

Comment: Is it okay to light all candles at the same time? If so, you could try overlaying the dark image with the light image; going from transparent to fully opaque - kind of a super simple morph. Not sure if that would look decent, maybe worth a try? If you combine that with the previous idea, it would look even better. But still, all of them would come on at the same time...

Comment: It doesn't look all that bad I guess? https://jsfiddle.net/vqyeaL4o/

Comment: @PaulCo I'm curious, did you manage to find any (other) solutions (or ideas for approaches) to this problem? Did you try out some other things? I would love to see this live.

Comment: @domdom Still thinking about it, however I'll have to find a solution quickly so I might try yours if I don't come up with something better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to light each candle individually, I wouldn't know how to do that without using too many images, hence too much bandwidth. I can therefore not provide a solution that perfectly suits your requirements. I will, however, suggest an interim solution that might work until someone comes up with something better.

**Idea:**
Group the 30+ candles into three chunks, as they seem to be arranged in roughly three rows.
Although a bit tricky, the rock geometry does lend itself to be cut out accordingly as well.

**Breakdown:**

- Create four pictures / layers:

  1. All dark
  2. One row lit
  3. Two rows lit
  4. All rows lit
- Use JPG, as small as possible (maybe 1280px in width, ~70% quality)
- Instead of using `img`, use one `div` with CSS `background-image` per layer
- Place all layers on top of each other (layer 4 on top) with `position: absolute`
- Use JavaScript to fade in another layer whenever a third of your page has loaded

The reason for using `background-image` is that you can easily use CSS to stretch the `div` containers to 100% `width` and `height` (assuming that the whole thing is supposed to be full screen) and make the images adapt to any resolution and aspect ratio easily. Upscaling a 1280px wide JPG to 1920px usually looks pretty okay, but you will have to play with image size and JPG quality to hit the sweet spot. With my suggested setup (see above), all four images should end up being about 400 to 500 KB combined.

**Example:**
<sup><sub>Note that this is a rough mockup based on your first and last frame - you can surely do much better with the original material at hand.</sub></sup>

```js
var timer = new Array(3);
var fader = new Array(3);
var layer = new Array(3);

function fade() {
  for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    layer[i]  = document.getElementById("s" + (i+1));
   layer[i].style.opacity = 0.0;
    clearTimeout(timer[i]);
    clearInterval(fader[i]);
    start(i);
  }
}

function start(i) {
  timer[i] = setTimeout(function() {
    fader[i] = setInterval(opacity, 20, i);
  }, (2000*i));
}

function opacity(i) {
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(layer[i], null);
  var opacity = parseFloat(style.getPropertyValue("opacity"));
  if (opacity >= 1) {
    clearInterval(fader[i]);
  } else {
    layer[i].style.opacity = (opacity + 0.01);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 417px;
}

.candles {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.0;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

#s0 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ZQqeebI.jpg);
  opacity: 1.0;
}

#s1 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ah7UP3x.jpg);
}

#s2 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/zLgBA5x.jpg);
}

#s3 {
  background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/ar4w18n.jpg);
}

button {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="s0" class="candles"></div>
  <div id="s1" class="candles"></div>
  <div id="s2" class="candles"></div>
  <div id="s3" class="candles"></div>
</div>
<button onclick="fade()">Fade</button>
```

Here is an [external link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j26mL7zz/1/).

Comment: That's an interesting way to do it ! Thanks a lot, i'll just wait for another answer out of curiosity but will likely choose yours

Comment: I sure hope someone comes up with something even better; am curious myself. I wonder if Flash would offer a better way of doing such a thing, but my knowledge of Flash is limited (and I'm not sure how well it is supported these days). Also, I just noticed that your image is made up of a limited number of colors; maybe PNG with a limited palette + dithering could help reduce file size even further; but that's something to experiment with I guess.